# How to use a Analysis Services processed data model

Tags: sql-server, prediction, sql-server-data-tools

I've just started to use Microsoft Analysis Services in SQL Server Data tools for clustering data and trained a Model. now I can query data and predict values in Mining Structures designer under the Mining Model Prediction tab.
The Question is how to use this model and predict values some where else(e.g. ASP app)? Can I declare a User defined function in sqlserver which uses this model? if yes, how? and if no, what's the best practice? 
I've searched in google and read the Microsoft docs but did not find anything related to my question.
 thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some search and watching some videos about the Microsoft Data Tools, It's seems that I should use `SISS`, which let me execute packages and extract predicted data whenever I want.